# how to create a alert box in android alternative presents?

Tags: java, android

**Create an alert box that show alternative during application run**
I want to alert box that appear even time when my app is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You have to put Shared preference that contains logic of number of times your app has been opened*

```
AlertDialog dialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder alert;

alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Select Language");
        alert.setSingleChoiceItems(bhasha, -1,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // do your stufe }
```

Comment: nice idea but I finding that logic

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple boolean as a flag value to show alert. You may need to save your boolean flag somewhere, perhaps in Shared Preferences and upon init you can implement something like following

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
Boolean isShown = prefs.getBoolean("isShown", false);

// Check Boolean Flag
if(isShown) {

    // Your Alert Snippet
}

// Inverse Flag Value
prefs.edit().putBoolean("isShown", !isShown).commit();
```